# Can I read SQLite datatime field as raw string?

Tags: sqlite, datetime, sqldatareader

I have public SQLite database, a lot of computer can write data to that DB. Unfortunately, Datetime format in different computer is different.

Sqlite can store different Datatime format

[image: 1]

Sqlite normally save data from different computer to Datatime field, but reading data with standard way by SQLiteDataReader (System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.116.0) is impossible, "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

One way is change field format to string, but for many reason this is not a best way in this project. Maybe there are exist another way - to read record as raw data without checking datatype. Is it possible?

Comment: You can read it as a string but how would this help?

Comment: @forpas, How is possible? I read this field as ~Dim X as string = RDR1("LastRezero")~, where RDR1 is: ~Dim RDR1 As SQLiteDataReader = CMD1.ExecuteReader~ - so this is simple reading as string. And receive error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: Why did you define `LastReZero` as `datetime`? There is no such data type in SQLite, just like there are no `mediumtext`, `varchar` and `int(11)`: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. For strings and string dates you should use `TEXT` as data type.

Comment: @forpas. Interesting, but of course you are right, this is solution. There are no official DataTime type.